Can the outcome of a fuzzy set Qualitative Comparative Analysis (fsQCA) can be a crisp set？
For example, I aim to analyze factors such as age, IQ, and other variables that impact whether individuals enroll in college. Is it appropriate to use fsQCA and code the outcome variable as 1 or 0?
